# OSGeoLive Error: unable to locate package qgis-examples

Tags: qgis, osgeo-live, apt-get

I'm trying to upgrade my QGIS to the latest Testing (2.99) version via a complete reinstall.

I did this before by removing it first using

```
 sudo apt-get remove qgis* grass*
```

But now, I can get past this first step because I encounter an error saying something like:

```
E: Unable to locate package qgis-examples
```

, and there is a similar error about not being able to locate `grassdata` from `apt-get`. This prevents anything including a `apt-get install -s`. I've tried to revert back to a much earlier OSGeo Live VM (10.5) back in April/2017 when it was first released. Still, the same errors occur.

I don't understand how this could have happened. I've removed `qgis` and `grass` before without an issue (and had an older version of QGIS 2.99 successfully installed).

Has anyone encountered a similar issue when removing `qgis`, or know a fix for this error?